# virtctl works when executed via command line but not from php exec()

Tags: php, kubernetes, exec, kubectl, phpseclib

I am trying to run kubectl virt commands to manage my virtual machine via PHP. First, I log in to my server with phpseclib with the following code:

```
$ssh = new SSH2('localhost');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'rootPassword')) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}
```

This part works fine, and when I try to run `$ssh->exec('whoami && echo $PATH')`, I get the following output:

```
root
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

But, whenever I try to run `kubectl virt` via PHP, I get the following output:

```
error: unknown command "virt" for "kubectl"
```

`kubectl` and `kubectl virt` work perfectly fine when I run them via terminal but somehow do not work with PHP exec(). I also tried to check the `$PATH` via terminal and I get a different output:

```
/root/.krew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I thought that it may be because of `$PATH` but the interesting part is when I try to run `sudo kubectl virt` via terminal I also get the same error:

```
error: unknown command "virt" for "kubectl"
```

At that point, I am completely lost and don't even know where to look for a problem. I am thankful for all the answers.

Comment: Could that command be defined as an alias? Maybe you got something in your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: `$ssh->exec('kubectl virt');` is basically the same thing as `ssh localhost 'kubectl virt'`. Do you get the same error with `ssh localhost 'kubectl virt'`?

Comment: I get the exact same error when I run `ssh localhost 'kubectl virt`

Comment: Well, that eliminates phpseclib as a possible source of the problem, at the very least!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are issuing ad-hoc ssh commands, you are not using interactive shell, and depending on your default shell behavior it may or may not load your .bashrc file . See https://serverfault.com/questions/936746/bashrc-is-not-sourced-on-ssh-command and [Running command via ssh also runs .bashrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546333/running-command-via-ssh-also-runs-bashrc/16547623#16547623) for more details.

So by default, krew modifies your `PATH` variable, and appends it's bin path to it, i.e. my config contains `export PATH="${KREW_ROOT:-$HOME/.krew}/bin:$PATH"`. But what exactly is kubectl plugin? Usually it's just a single binary, with kubectl-*plugin_name* name. So by invoking `which kubectl-virt` you can easily know where is your virt binary located and invoke it directly, so something like

```
$ssh->exec('~/.krew/bin/kubectl-virt')
```

should work

The other way is to modify PATH all by yourself, setting `PATH=$PATH:~/.krew/bin` should make it work, at least in my case

```
ssh localhost 'PATH=$PATH:~/.krew/bin kubectl virt'
```

worked nicely.

You can try to force loading of .bashrc in your shell configuration, but personally i think it's a bad practice, and ssh commands are not usually loading rc files for a reason, command execution speed and consistency between systems are the first things that come to mind.

Regarding sudo, it's actually not that surprising, because without `-E` or `-i` flags it won't load your current environment / won't start interactive shell. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228314/sudo-command-doesnt-source-root-bashrc for more info